# SQL Statement to read >1000 values in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, select, mariadb

I've currently got a SQL select statement that successfully does the following where it gives me  the status from last two days:

```
SELECT c.host, from_unixtime(a.clock), a.value, b.name 
FROM
    zabbix.history_uint a, 
    zabbix.items b, 
    zabbix.hosts c, 
    zabbix.groups g, 
    zabbix.hosts_groups hg 
WHERE c.hostid = hg.hostid 
AND g.groupid = hg.groupid 
AND b.itemid=a.itemid 
AND b.hostid=c.hostid 
AND (b.name = "nodeAlive") 
AND a.clock > 1539489622 
AND c.host = "LONDON01";
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------------------+-------+-----------+
| host       | from_unixtime(a.clock) | value | name      |
+------------+------------------------+-------+-----------+
| LONDON01   | 2018-11-13 00:15:35    |     1 | nodeAlive |
| LONDON01   | 2018-11-14 00:15:35    |     1 | nodeAlive |
| LONDON01   | 2018-11-13 00:15:35    |     1 | nodeAlive |
| LONDON01   | 2018-11-14 00:15:35    |     1 | nodeAlive |
| LONDON01   | 2018-11-13 00:15:35    |     1 | nodeAlive |
| LONDON01   | 2018-11-14 00:15:35    |     1 | nodeAlive |
+------------+------------------------+-------+-----------+
```

I now need to find the status of MADRID03, TORONTO52, NEWYORK77 and >1000 other hosts.

Is it possible to execute this from a text file & output to another file? If so, how would the syntax be modified?

Thanks & appreciate it

Comment: Are you getting the status of all hosts in the table for the previous two days? Or is the `> 1000 other hosts` only a subset of all the hosts in the table? And do you actually want duplicate results as per your output example? These can be filtered using `SELECT DISTINCT...`.

Comment: Ah! I am wanting the status of all 1000+ hosts. Having duplicate output is okay, although I will go ahead with the tweaked statement to include DISTINCT.

Comment: I want to avoid typing out the 1000+ hosts in the SELECT DISTINCT statement

Comment: Are you using a language like PHP to do this?

Comment: I'm not using PHP (nor know how to). Am using purely SQL statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as changing

```
AND c.host = "LONDON01"
```

to

```
AND c.host IN ("LONDON01", "MADRID03", "TORONTO52", "NEWYORK77", "TORONT9999", ...)
```

Or, maybe it would be easier to put the 1000+ names in a table and do a `JOIN`?  Or do you already have then in a table?

Have you stopped to think how many rows will be in the ouput?

You could (for coding simplicity) change

```
a.clock > 1539489622
```

to

```
a.clock > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

(or use `... >= CURDATE() ...` if you want to start at midnight)

There seems to be no reason to `JOIN` to `groups`.

Comment: _"There seems to be no reason to JOIN to groups."_ - Joining groups would eliminate hosts without groups.

Comment: Okay, so my solution was to paste the 1500 hosts into Excel such that they were all under column 'B'. Then pasted <"> from A1 to A1500. Pasted <"> from C1 to C1500. Then pasted <,> from D1 to D1500. Then did a "=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1)" from E1 through E1500. Then copied E1 through E1500 and did a Paste Special Values into a new Sheet --> Sheet2. From Sheet2, I copied the 1500 cells which included the hostnames with quotation marks and commas and Paste Special Transpose into another Sheet --> Sheet3.

Comment: From here, I copied the row and pasted into the SELECT statement such that it's .... AND c.host IN ("LONDON01", "MADRID03", TORONTO52", .....). This was a bit brute force, but it worked. Thanks fubar and Rick James

Comment: @stitch70 - Perhaps the real solution is to abandon Excel?

Comment: @RickJames Agreed, Ideally i would like to not have used Excel and have liked to use an input file

Answer (score 0):

You can read your server list into a temporary table and execute a subquery.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE servers (name varchar(100)) ENGINE=MEMORY ;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/server/listfile' INTO TABLE servers;
SELECT .....  AND c.host IN (SELECT name FROM servers);
```

If your server list doesn't change often, you can make your table permanent and update when needed.